# why assign an enum instance to the other enum, when I change the value of enum, it doesn't effect to the other

Tags: java, enums

Because enum type is a set of named values, I want to use it as states of state machine.

However, when I assign one enum instance to the other, and change the value of former instance, I expect that the other enum instance has the same reference but it doesn't, and as result, the value changing does not take effect to the other (the later one).

I am wondering why? and how can I make this logic happen by using enum type?

Here is my sample code.

```
public class Test {
    public enum TestEnum {
        A, B, C
    }

    public static class InnerClass {
        private String str;
        private int i;
        private Integer integer;

        private InnerClass(String s, int i, Integer integer) {
            this.str = s;
            this.i = i;
            this.integer = integer;
        }

        public String getStr() {
            return str;
        }

        public void setStr(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        public int getI() {
             return i;
        }

        public void setI(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public int getInteger() {
            return integer;
        }

        public void setInteger(Integer i) {
             this.integer = i;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "str: " + str + ", i: " + i + ", integer: " + integer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass("test string", 1, 1);
        TestEnum enum1 = TestEnum.A;
        System.out.println(innerClass.toString());
        System.out.println(enum1);

        InnerClass innerClass2 = innerClass;
        TestEnum enum2 = enum1;

        innerClass.setStr("new test string");
        innerClass.setI(2);
        innerClass.setInteger(2);
        enum1 = TestEnum.B;

        System.out.println(innerClass2.toString());
        System.out.println(enum2);
        System.out.println(enum1);
    }
}
```

And the output are:
str: test string, i: 1, integer: 1
A
str: new test string, i: 2, integer: 2
A
B

Obviously, You can see you change enum1 doesn't effect to enum2. 
why? and if I want it happen, how could I change my code?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking here: this is just how references work. Are you aware that `innerClass` and `innerClass2` refer to the same instance, so if you printed `innerClass` after you print `innerClass2` you'd see the same output.

Comment: It would also help if you removed the code in your question that is not relevant to the question.  For instance, the `InnerClass` and everything the depends on it have no relevance to the behavior of the `enum1` and `enum2` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of an enum type variable kind like a primitive type variable. I would argue that all primitive type variables have a finite number of states.

In your case think off `TestEnum` as for example `int` type.
When you assign a value to a variable of `TestEnum` type, it's like assigning a number value to `int` type variable.

```
// this defines 2 'buckets' in memory storing states of 2 variables
TestEnum a = TestEnum.A, b = TestEnum.B;
// this simply copies a state of variable b into variable a
// a and b are NOT pointers to the memory!
a = b;
// following simply replaces a state of variable b
// it has nothing to do with variable a
b = TestEnum.C;
// at that point a is TestEnum.B
// b has TestEnum.C value
```

If you want to keep many "references" to some values/variables and change their state by accessing any of them, simply follow the same way as you did using your `InnerClass` type, `innerClass` and `innerClass2` variables, and store variable and its state within such object.

```
public class Test {
    public enum TestEnum {
        A, B, C
    }

    public static class InnerClass {
        private TestEnum testEnum;

        private InnerClass(TestEnum testEnum) {
            this.testEnum = testEnum;
        }

        public TestEnum getTestEnum() {
            return testEnum;
        }

        public void setTestEnum(TestEnum testEnum) {
            this.testEnum = testEnum;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "testEnum: " + testEnum;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass(TestEnum.A);
        System.out.println(innerClass.toString());

        InnerClass innerClass2 = innerClass;

        innerClass.setTestEnum( TestEnum.B );

        System.out.println(innerClass2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I am asking for. Great.